# Org-mode: Subtree of all unckecked checkboxes

Tags: org-mode

Consider an org-file like

```
* Heading
** Subheading
- [X] checkbox 1
- [ ] checkbox 2
- [X] checkbox 3
** Sub 2
*** Subsub 1 
- [ ] checkbox 4
- [X] checkbox 5
etc.
```

Is there a convenient way to see just all unchecked checkboxes and hiding the other content (in my example checkboxes 2 and 4), i.e. narrow down to a "unchecked checkbox tree".

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a `sparse tree`  but that only works at the headline level, not at the list item level.  `org-map-entries` should be able to find those headlines easily enough, but what do you want to do with them afterwards? You might also investigate the various statistics cookies that are available: see [Checkboxes](https://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html) in the Org manual.

Comment: @NickD: I want an fast overview of all unchecked items. But maybe I shouldn't use the checkboxes at all and change for example `- [X] checkbox 1` to `*** DONE checkbox 1`.

Comment: Since first contact with org-mode I was confused about the point that the TODO tag works on headlines level rather than on item level (and rather than inline).